# if else statement in rails - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**This is my views/application.html.erb**

```
<div class="table">
 <h1 align="center"><p class ="navbar-fouls" style="color:#48A5E3" >Recent Fouls</p></h1>
   <table align="center" style="width:100%">
     <tr>
        <% if Foul.any? %>
          <%= @foul.law %>
        <% else %>
          <p class="text-center" style="center">Game has not started yet.</p>
        <% end %>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

**I am getting the error**

```
undefined method `law' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #79):

```
76      <table align="center" style="width:100%">
77        <tr>
78           <% if Foul.any? %>
79             <%= @foul.law %>
80           <% else %>
81             <p class="text-center" style="center">Game has not started yet.</p>
82           <% end %>
```

**I have this in my foul controller**
I do not understand why it is giving me this error when @foul is clearly defined.

```
class FoulsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @fouls = Foul.all
  end

  def show
    @foul = Foul.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @foul = Foul.new
  end


  def create
    @foul = Foul.new(fouls_params)
    if @foul.save
        redirect_to(:action => "index")
    else
        render("new")
    end
  end

  def edit
        @foul = Foul.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @foul = Foul.find(params[:id])
        if @foul.update_attributes(fouls_params)
            redirect_to(:action => "show", :id => @foul.id)
        else
            render("index")
        end
  end

  def destroy
    foul = Foul.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
  end


  private
  def fouls_params
    params.require(:foul).permit(:law, :description)
  end
end`
```

Comment: That's a strange name for a view template file -- please confirm.

Comment: @foul is not being set correctly.

Comment: Also, which controller method triggered it? (Maybe just add the relevant log snippet?)

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting your controller to supply an `@foul` instance variable. Here, the controller set `@foul = nil` (unless it's `index` and `@foul` isn't getting set at all).

Comment: This is some of what is in my controller(I couldn't fit it all)
`class FoulsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
   @fouls = Foul.all
  end

  def show
   @foul = Foul.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @foul = Foul.new
  end

end`

Comment: Please add that to your question -- it'll be easier to format & read there :-)

Comment: Where does it say that `@foul = nil` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for `Foul.any?` in `views/application.html.erb` you should probably check for `if @foul`

`Foul.any?` makes a call to your database, but `if @foul` checks what the variable is actually set to.

```
<% if @foul %>
   <%= @foul.law %>
<% else %>
   <p class="text-center" style="center">Game has not started yet.</p>
 <% end %>
```